# How to enabled TRACE method nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, configuration, apache2

I got my web page running on my Apache server behind nginx reverse proxy. At this point, my apache server responds to trace requests, but when I make the request to the reverse proxy address, nginx returns 405. How can I set this response to return 200 from apache? (Apache server is running on localhost:81)

Here is the my nginx.conf ;

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location ~ / {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:81;
        proxy_pass_header Server;

    }  
}

}
```